# How to update gcloud python27 microversion

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

When I run

```
gcloud init
```

and then cd to my project folder and run

```
 dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

I get the following warning:

```
Your python27 micro version is below 2.7.12, our current production version
```

How do I update the micro version? I'm on a Mac

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your local machine's python (or your virtual-env's python if you are running `dev_appserver.py` in a virtual env)

The right answer on how to do this depends on how you setup your python. I setup mine with homebrew https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python

If your python IS up to date, then you have multiple pythons running around on your machine, and `dev_appserver.py` is grabbing a different one that you are expecting it to find.

This is the source code in `.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py` that is producing that warning:

```
  def check_python_version(self, runtime):
    """Check the python version and give proper warnings if necessary."""
    if runtime == 'python27':
      if sys.version_info[1] < 7:
        logging.warning('You are creating a python27 module, but your python '
                        'minor version is below 2.7.')
      elif sys.version_info[2] < runtime_factories.PYTHON27_PROD_VERSION[2]:
        logging.warning('Your python27 micro version is below %s, our '
                        'current production version.',
                        '.'.join(map(str,
                                     runtime_factories.PYTHON27_PROD_VERSION)))
```